# How can I resize and repaint the Hamburger icon on codename one sidemenu?

Tags: sidebar, codenameone

I've implemented the CodeNameOne sidemenu with the hamburger icon and it works great. My problem, though, is that I can't seem to manipulate the icon. I can't repaint it, I can't resize, and it looks too big compared to the rest of my application. Is there a way to resize it, repaint it, or even replace with a different icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the designer tool to open your theme and under the constants tab add "sideMenuImage" entry and point it to your own image(make sure this image is a multi image to support the many devices resolutions).